# setInterval - 'interval' is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, time, setinterval

I have a setTimer function in my react app which uses the `setInterval` hook to increment my `sec` variable.

```
  function setTimer() {
    if (!started) {
      setStarted(true);
      const interval = setInterval(() => {
        setSec(prevProps => {
          return {sec: prevProps.sec+1}
        })
      }, 1000)
    }
  }
```

But then above this method, I have a `onFinish` method which is called when an condition is met. In this method, I use `clearInterval` and pass `interval`. Now this worked properly when I used a class component because I had access to `this`. But now I have switched from a class component to a functional component. And I don't think the program recognized my `interval` variable.

```
 function onFinish() {
    if (text.length-1 === symbols) {
      clearInterval(interval);
      setPopup(true)
      setFinished(true)
      setStarted(false)
    }
  }
```

I've just recently started learning react and js in general so this might be a very obvious answer, but for the love of God I can figure it out. How can I avoid this error?

Comment: `const interval` is not visible outside the `setTimer` function (or even outside the `if` where it is declared). You need a variable or a property that can be shared between these two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

const is block scoped, so your variable is not accessible outside the curly braces : `{}`.

```
 let interval = null;
 function setTimer() {
    if (!started) {
      setStarted(true);
     interval = setInterval(() => {
        setSec(prevProps => {
          return {sec: prevProps.sec+1}
        })
      }, 1000)
    }
  }
```

Comment: question, what would let interval = useRef(null); do?

Comment: useRef is for values you want to persist for lifetime of component, between rerenders. You can omit it and simply use a variable if your state is not updating by the time you want to use clearInterval.

Comment: I have edited the code in the same way. If you feel your component will rerender in between, then you will have to use useRef and i will edit accordingly.

Comment: ok. That makes sense. It work btw, I will accept the post after 8min pass as SO has some weird cool down thing